# Can't get value from HTML tag attribute "value" to onClick script

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I suppose to have some value from `<button>` tag but it is **undefined** when I click the button. What am I doing wrong?

I use `function(e)` to get attributes and then `e.value = undefined`.

```
runTest(elem){
    let url = 'someUrl';
    let path = elem.value;
    console.log(path);
    $.post(url, {
        path: path
    }, function(data, status){
        alert('Data: ' + data +  "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <div className="btn-group dropright">
                <button type="button" className="btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Wraith
                </button>
                <div className="dropdown-menu">
                    <button className="dropdown-item" value='someValue' onClick={this.runTest}>Get value</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `onClick` listener receives [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object as argument, not DOM element.

Comment: you bind.this() the method?

Comment: this is not the way react apps usually work. better set that value to the `props` of your component and do something like `<button className="dropdown-item" value={this.props.someValue} onClick={this.runTest}>Get value</button>`

Comment: elem.traget.value 

was the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onClick event fires an event.

So it's the event which is passed to your runTest function, not the element.

```
runTest(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
}
```